# How to switch a boolean value of an object instantiated by a class? Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, properties, boolean

I'm trying to implement a turn based game between 2 players and I have a property which will indicate who's turn is up.

```
class Player{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.playerTurn = true;
  }
}

var p = new Player('mike');
var k = new Player('jeff');
```

other than running `k.playerTurn = false;` right after the instantiation, is there a more elegant way to flip the playerTurn property of the player k at the moment of instantiation?

Comment: make it a constructor argument

Comment: var k = new Player('jeff',false); this won't work

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer you why it won't work, since this is my question...console logging both players will instantiating them with true

Comment: Obviously your constructor would need to be `constructor(name, isTurn) { ...; this.playerTurn = isTurn; }`…

Comment: thanks, trying to wrap my head around your example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whose turn it is should not be a property of the player, but of the game state, e.g.:

```
class Game {
    constructor(players) {
        this.players = players;  // Player[]
        this.currentPlayer = players[0];
    }

    nextTurn() {
        // Or whatever your logic for rotating players is…
        this.players = this.players.concat([this.players.shift()]);
        this.currentPlayer = this.players[0];
    }
}

const game = new Game([new Player('jeff'), new Player('mike')]);
```